# Display messages in my custom theme, Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal

I just made a theme for my user pass page like this article:
[create custom theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/350634)

But there is no messages to displayed any more in my user-password.tpl.php
I print $messages in my theme but not displayed.

Comment: do you print $messages in page.tpl.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understand this wrong, but I guess you mean the System Messages e.g. "Edited Node successfully"?

I print messages above my main-content in my page.tpl.php:

```
<?php if ($messages): ?>
<div id="messages">
    <div class="section clearfix">
        <?php print $messages; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes exactly.I missed $messages from page.tpl

Comment: Yes solved thanks. But is there any way to display $messages in  my user-password.tpl in custom position?

Comment: I don't really see a reason to. But I think $messages is not available to print out in certain files. You can try to "cut and paste" the html-content from the messages-div to a custom div client-side width jquery: `$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#yourmessagesdiv).appendTo('#newcustompositiondiv);
});`